# responsive design: align div containing image text at the middle center

Tags: css

**I need to**

1.Middle center align a div(contentcontainer) which contains image and text inside another div container.

2.Render the image and text for different devices so it looks nicely on both mobile and desktop devices.

**Please note**

1.The content html for the image and text will be sent dynamically so the height of the content container is flexible.

2.The size of the original image and length of the text are different each time so the width and height of the maintainer cannot be fixed values

3.This needs to support android and ios browsers(mainly safari and chrome).

**JSFIDDLE*

http://jsfiddle.net/1o8vuqbd/1/

```
    <div id="maincontainer">
    <div id="contentcontainer">
        <img  src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
        <div style="text-align:left;">
            <div>This is the title</div>
            <div>This is the body</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    #maincontainer {
        height:100%;
        width:100%;
        padding:5px;
        background-color:red;
    }

    #contentcontainer {
        height:100%;
        width:100%;
        position: relative;
        background-color:pink;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Good pics. But where is your code?

Comment: thanks for the remainding. i just added the code.

Comment: Add a fiddle. It would be better for css

Comment: @user3801433 jsfiddle is added

Comment: is scroll horizontally or vertically allowable?

Comment: no, that is not allowed. the image and text shall be displayed within the given div. If the image and text div is too large, need to resize it responsively depending on the devices.

Answer (score 2):

**Here is the updated code.**

HTML:

```
<div id="maincontainer">
    <div id="contentcontainer">
            <img  src="http://placehold.it/150x150" style="float: left;">
            <div style="text-align:left;">
                <div>This is the title</div>
                <div>This is the body</div>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#maincontainer {
    height: 500px;
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
    background-color:red;
}

#contentcontainer {
   background-color: #FFC0CB;
    overflow-y: auto;
    position: absolute;
    left: 25%;
    top: 25%;
    width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: thanks. but the width and height of the maintainer are dynamic instead of fixed.

Comment: Hey check this out [Click Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Varun_Chakervarti/xqg5j14v/4/) - 
Is this what you are looking for ??